# Hide messy rendered page until DomContentLoaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, server-side-rendering, umijs

My [website](https://dinf.net/items/35112/Zero-Trust) is showing messy components until DomContentLoaded.
I would like to show a loading-spinner or hide the content until page is loaded.
I'm using React SSR with UmiJS3.
[image: page loading progress as seen by Google]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use Suspense API from React but it doesn't support ssr right now but they recommend [Loadable components](https://github.com/gregberge/loadable-components) which referenced in [here](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy)